# Sagepay V3 protocol upgrade - OpenCart

Tags: upgrade, opencart2.x, opayo

Just been looking at upgrading a friend's website to SagePay V3, on a site that uses OpenCart.

We have upgraded OpenCart to v2, and installed an OpenCart extension to support SagePay protocol V3.

Having done all of that, it all seems to work and we have successfully placed an order, so pretty sure its all good to go.

I'm not too familiar with SagePay, and there it is still saying in SagePay that we need to upgrade (albeit with a note saying if it has been upgraded the message will disappear within 48 hours).

So I'm really just wondering if there is anything to do on the SagePay site to upgrade, or if the upgrade is covered by whatever changes the OpenCart extension will have made, i.e. presumably changing the required fields that get sent in the transaction string from the site to SagePay?

If anyone could shed any light that would be great.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It's been a little while since I implemented this but according to their docs, it will all be set up once you have completed a transaction and a refund on the test server.. but I'm sure it wasn't that simple in reality and I had to call them to switch it over. Please see the documentation here: http://www.sagepay.co.uk/support/find-an-integration-document/form-integration

Probably best to call them once you have placed the order and refund and get them to confirm for you to be 100% sure!